# how to create an association class with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities one named Cashier and the other user, and I have a relationship of more than several n: n so this creates an entity (association). But A user uses a checkout at a defined date, so a date property is in the association that is created so a class must be created to specify that entity in the code. how does this class create with jpa annotation?

**Classe User**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String matricule;

    private String password;

    private String nom;

    private String prenom;

    private String codeExploitant;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "utilisateur")
    private List<Operation> operation;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Caisse> caisse;
}
```

**Class Checkout**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Caisse implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long code;

  private String libelle;

  private int numeroCompte;

  private String agence;

  private long montantInitial;

  private long montantFinal;

  private String periode;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="utilisateur")
  private Utilisateur utilisateur;

}
```

**Class UserCheckout**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UtilisateurCaisse {

  @Id
  private String matricule;

  @Id
  private Long idCaisse;

  private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

Also can I add a controller of the class of this association?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html.
ManyToMany#targetEntity is what I would use

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/